# When to use "profit" vs. "profits"?

Tags: grammatical-number, pluralia-tantum

I have noticed that some authors refer to the amount of money that a firm makes (net of costs) as "the firm's profit," while other authors refer to it as "the firm's profits." For example, consider the following sentences,

- "The firm made 5 million in profits." vs. "The firm made a profit of 5 million."
- "The CEO wanted to maximize the firm's profits." vs. "The CEO wanted to maximize the profit of the firm."

Which form is correct? Is one form more common than the other?

If the context matters, most of my audience consists of U.S. or international academics.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of singular and plural? Possibly, a group having many businesses, or a company having many products may use profits instead of profit.  In a balance-sheet, or profit and loss account, the singular form is often used, I think.

Comment: Thank you Ram. That makes a lot of sense to me. But I have noticed that many authors use the plural form when discussing a single firm and without making reference to multiple balance sheets.